# How can I replace words which are surrounded with special characters?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I want to remove words which are surrounded by special characters using `preg_replace()`:

```
$product_name =  'Choose a   : giFt ,';
$word = 'gift';
$regex = '/[-:,]?\b'.$word.'\b[-:,]?/i';
if(preg_match($regex, $product_name))
{
  $str = preg_replace($regex, "", trim($product_name));
}
echo $str;
```

output:

```
Choose a  :  ,
```

It works fine if there is no space means if my string is "Choose a   :giFt,".

My expected output is

```
Choose a
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try this :

```
$regex = '`:([^>]+),`';
```

But you must clean your code too, you don't need $regex and $regex_p

Answer (score 0):

Just add spaces in your character class:

```
$regex = '/[-:,\s]*\b'.$word.'\b[-:,\s]*/i';
```